# Many troubles trying to mount QNAP NFS server on Ubuntu mount point

Tags: ubuntu, mount, nfs

I have a [QNAP TS-251 NAS](https://www.qnap.com/i/en/product/model.php?II=195) with a pair of 4 GB drives set up as RAID 1, running as a server, mainly for backups. It has the default operating system, QTS 4.2.0 (2016/01/19), which I think is current. It's a customized flavor of Linux with a GUI interface that I run from my Windows desktop. It has IP number 169.254.100.101 on its Ethernet #1 port and 169.254.100.102 on its Ethernet #2 port.

As a client, I have an old Dell (Core 2 Duo T8100) laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It's connected to the QNAP's #2 Ethernet port, and its IP number is 169.254.100.99.

*Note:* From here I'll include background details that can probably be skipped (but answer "Why would you do this?" questions I anticipate) in [brackets].

There's also a Windows desktop connected to the QNAP's #1 Ethernet port, which is involved with this only to run the QNAP's GUI. I can also use PuTTY from it to the QNAP if I need a command line

[The QNAP comes with several default shared folders: Download, Multimedia, Public, Recordings, Web, homes.]

I created a shared folder named CrashPlan on the QNAP server, and a mount point on the Ubuntu client named /mnt/QNAP-CrashPlan. I installed NFS client packages on the client with `sudo apt-get install portmap nfs-client` [and installed autofs with `sudo apt-get install autofs` in an unsuccessful attempt to diagnose problems].

Following advice in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799052/mount-qnap-nfs-share-on-linux-os), I gave NFS access rights, host/IP/network 169.254.*, permission read/write, and squash option NO_ROOT_SQUASH. The anonymous boxes remained grayed out.

So, in the moment of truth, from the client, I tried `sudo mount 169.254.100.102:/CrashPlan /mnt/QNAP-CrashPlan` and `sudo mount -t nfs 169.254.100.102:/CrashPlan /mnt/QNAP-CrashPlan`, and got `mount.nfs: Connection timed out` in both cases.

In an attempt to diagnose the problem, I tried `showmount -e 169.254.100.102`, but it replied `clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Unable to receive: errno 111 (Connection refused)`.

I've searched a lot and tried a lot, but I haven't found any further paths to diagnose the problem. Any ideas?

I will edit in more details as needed. Also, this might deserve a "qnap" tag, but I don't have create tag permission.

[*[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) details:* The reason I named the shared folder that I created CrashPlan is that I tried to run the QNAP as a CrashPlan server. I wasn't able to get that to work except by mounting the CrashPlan folder as a Windows drive, using `net use` to mount it, and running a separate user-mode client instance of CrashPlan on Windows, because Windows doesn't allow services access to `net use` drives. Running the CrashPlan server on my old Ubuntu laptop with the QNAP mounted through NFS was described as a configuration that avoided that issue.]

Comment: on the qnap, did you do "Network Services" -> "NFS Service" -> "enable nfs"? Do you have a firewall (iptables) on your ubuntu?

Comment: Yes to enabling NFS on the QNAP. I haven't set up a firewall on the Ubuntu machine, unless it's there by default. Thanks for pointing me toward something I can investigate.

Comment: Are you 100% sure `169.254.*` is valid setting? I'm not sure that wildcards are permitted in IP addresses. I'd try first with the specific IP address of your computer. I think the correct syntax for IP address ranges is actually `169.254.0.0/255.255.0.0`.  http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NFS-HOWTO/server.html. I tried using a wildcard, and it didn't work for me, so I just put the specific IP address in. I haven't tried the "slash plus mask" syntax. I'd be interested in seeing if that fixes your problem.

Comment: This further confirms my suspicion that wildcards are not valid for IP addresses: http://linux.die.net/man/5/exports

Comment: @MichaelBylstra, the cautions against wildcards look very helpful. I'll try it as soon as I have a chance to tinker with the configuration again.

Comment: is eth1 at qnap 169.254.100.102 and eth0 169.254.100.101 ? That shouldn't work. Can you ping the qnap from the ubuntu box ? wildcards isn't allowed in ip-addresses in etc/exports , use something like 169.254.100.0/24.  Wildcards is allowed in  domain name matching so something like 'rw=*.something.com' is ok.

Comment: rw=169.254.100.0/24 should work, but : what is the different machines idea about routing ??? What do 'ip route show' says on the ubuntu and the qnap machine ?

Comment: The trouble with  routing can explain the portmapper refusal.

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses starting by `169.254.*` are an error. Those are [link local addresses](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5735), meant to allow communication between hosts in the same subnet. You need to fix that first, maybe it can be fixed by setting up a DHCP server on the NAS.

The rest should be OK after that.

Comment: ... or fixed IP addresses. Right, you ought to use 10.0.0.0/8 or 192.168.0.0/16 for these things.

Answer (score 0):

I had this after a recent update. I disabled NFS4 on the Qnap and enabled it on the Qnap and then it worked for the client.